# Wipe out and recreate XP Mode start menu entries in Windows 7

Tags: microsoft-virtual-pc, start-menu, windows-xp-mode

Windows XP Mode start menu entries are duplicated into the Windows 7 start menu. I removed and rearranged the entries somewhat in XP Mode. They're still showing up in Windows 7 start menu. I would like for all of those XP Mode entries to disappear and then reappear as per what I made the start menu look like in XP Mode. Basically, wipe out and have it created anew. How can I trigger such a procedure?